# How to store Logs from AppleWatch even if the AppleWatch is not connected to a Mac

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, oslog

I am trying to store the Logs from the App I wrote (Apple Watch only, Swift/SwiftUI) to access them later, as soon as I connect my iPhone to my Mac.
Is there any possibility to store the Logs on the AppleWatch or iPhone throughout the day and access them later? 
It would be great if I could save the entries of `os_log`, since I create all my Logs with it.
I was hoping to be able to save all the logs of my app for later with something like a self-written debugging profile but I didn't managed to achieve this.

I write Logs in the App like:

```
import os.log
ExtensionDelegate = OSLog(subsystem: "com.my.watchapp", category: "ExtensionDelegate")
os_log(.info, log: .ExtensionDelegate, "Perform any final initialization of your application in applicationDidFinishLaunching")
```

I'm only able to see the current logs in the Console App on my Mac if my iPhone is connected but I would like to see all the log entries of, for example, the last day.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance